# Foundation 6 sticky not working when using Jquery on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, zurb-foundation

I'm running Foundation 6 on my WordPress website, I have a sticky header that works fine. But the header stops working when I add my own Jquery function that uses an onscroll function. Anyone knows why?

JS:**

```js
jQuery(window).on('scroll', function(){
 var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
 if(scrollTop > 265) 
 {
     jQuery('.panel-grid-cell').addClass('hidden')();
 }
});
```

**HTML:

```
<div id="top" class="show-for-<?php echo $breakpoint ?>" data-sticky-container>
    <div class="sticky" data-sticky data-top-anchor="pgc-226-pgstart-0:top" data-btm-anchor="content:bottom" data-options="marginTop: 0" data-sticky-on="<?php echo $breakpoint ?>" style="width:100%;z-index:99;" id="menucontainer">
        <div class="top-bar row" id="top-bar-menu" style="z-index:99;">
            <div class="top-bar-left"> 
            <?php if( get_field('website_logo', 'option') ): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>"><img class="site-logo" src="<?php the_field('website_logo', 'option'); ?>" height="<?php the_field('logo_height', 'option'); ?>" alt="site-logo"></a>
                <a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>"><img class="site-logo-small site-logo-scroll" src="<?php the_field('website_logo_small', 'option'); ?>" height="<?php the_field('logo_height', 'option'); ?>" alt="site-logo"></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="top-bar-right">
                <?php joints_top_nav(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't have an html tag with the class `.panel-grid-cell'`

Comment: Are there any errors in dev console?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer; I made a typo in my javascript code:

```
jQuery('.panel-grid-cell').addClass('hidden')();
```

should be:

```
jQuery('.panel-grid-cell').addClass('hidden');
```